# Dataframe: How to compare two columns with string values?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe. Some columns have values like $60,000. The problem is when the table is scraped They are split into two columns. One column has $ and next column with the same header has 60,000. Both are taken as string. I need to remove the column which has $s. How to do that?
Ex:

[image]

Comment: Your question title is talking about comparing two columns with String values, but your question body is about something totally different. What exactly are you looking for?
And can you give an example of what you already tried? (no screenshots, just paste it in the question itself)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I want to know how to remove unwanted columns. They are in currency format with commas ($X,XXX,XXX). Upon scraping it split into two columns. I need to figure out a way to find the columns which stores $s and remove them.

Comment: I tried this: names = list(df)
                    for i in range(1, len(names)-1):
                        if df[names[i]].all()>df[names[i+1]].all():
                            print("fist column is big")
                        elif df[names[i+1]].all()>df[names[i]].all():
                            print("second column is big") But it did not work since the values are string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combien them like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['$','$','$'], 'b':[10,20,30]})

df['a'] + df['b'].astype(str)

Out[75]: 
0    $10
1    $20
2    $30
dtype: object
```

---

If both columns have an identical name, you can either rename one of them before doing the above solution, or group it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['$','$','$'], 'b':[10,20,30]})
df.columns = ['a', 'a']

df.applymap(str).groupby(['a'], level=0, axis=1).sum()

     a
0  $10
1  $20
2  $30
dtype: object
```

---

If you just want to remove all columns containing only `$` you can use this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['$','$','$'], 'b':[10,20,30]})

for col in df:
    if list(df[col].unique()) == ['$']:
        df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

Out[120]: 
    b
0  10
1  20
2  30
```

Comment: Excellent!. Thank you Andreas. Your second solution works. A slight change: It should be df= df.applymap(str).groupby(['a'], level=0, axis=1).sum().